# Can someone help me set this problem up? I'm not sure what to do for it

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

how should I go about doing this problem?

Comment: What have you done on the subject ?

Comment: Do you understand what they mean by "at least" 4?

Comment: this is a final exam review. So all of general statistics. i just need a refresher because we learned this in the begining

Comment: yes, greater than or equal to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *event*, expressed by the introduced *random variable* $X$ is $X\ge 4$.

Now $X$ is given a discrete distribution of the probabilities of 'elementary events' $(X=n)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

We are looking for $P(X\ge 4)\ =\ P(X=4)+P(X=5)$ now.

Comment: oh wow I really overthought that one... that was easy! Thanks for the refresher!